# How to access QMainWindow from another class

Tags: c++, qt

// mainwindow.h

```
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include "parseTextFile.h"

class MainWindow:public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(void);

private:
    Ui_mainWindow ui;
    parseFile *fileParse;

public slots:
    int onOkButtonClick();
};
```

// mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(void)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    connect(ui.OkButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onOkButtonClick()));
}

int MainWindow::onOkButtonClick()
{
    fileParse = new parseFile(this);
    fileParse->parseTextFile();
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    MainWindow *mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

// parseTextFile.h

```
class parseFile
{
public:
    parseFile(QWidget *parent =0);
    ~parseFile();

    int parseTextFile( );
};
```

// parseTextFile.cpp

```
#include "parseTextFile.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

parseFile::parseFile(QWidget *parent)
{
}

parseFile::~parseFile()
{
}

int parseFile::parseTextFile( )
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"a","b");
    return 0;
}
```

I can able to access parseTextFile method but i am getting error in QMessageBox. Is it the right way?
How to print QMessageBox in parseTextFile class?
anything needs to add in parseTextFile constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to QMessageBox::information as a parent is not a valid argument because parseFile is not a QWidget derived class.

For simple, just pass `nullptr` instead of `this` :

```
QMessageBox::information(nullptr ,"a","b");
```

In this case, the message box belongs to no one. It's will be closed by the user or when the application exits.

PS: you should release the memory after using fileParse to avoid memory leaks.

There are several ways to like with the main window (static pointer, singleton, top widgets enumeration,etc.) but the simplest one, that I thinks you intend to do, is to make parseFile class as QObject derived class and QMainWindow its parent.

```
class parseFile: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    parseFile(QWidget *parent =0);
    ~parseFile();

    int parseTextFile();
};

parseFile::parseFile(QWidget *parent)
:QObject(parent)
{
}
int parseFile::parseTextFile()
{
    QWidget * parentWidget = qobject_cast<QWidget *>( parent() ); //<-- QMainWindow instance

    QMessageBox::information( parentWidget, "a", "b");
    return 0;
}

int MainWindow::onOkButtonClick()
{
    fileParse = new parseFile(this);
    fileParse->parseTextFile( );

    //fileParse should be released by:
    //fileParse->deleteLater();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, great. Its working fine. But the QMessageBox window is not linked with the QMainWindow. The MessageBox window is displaying sepearately in center of the window. Is there any way to link both QMainWindow and QMessageBox?